# Bootstrap Column size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap to get two separated columns (not in the same row) to have the same height, which would be the height of the bigger element (a picture).

My layout is illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/v30u5zjd/

Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-height">
                <img src="http://www.onlinegamblingbible.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/small-Android_logo.png"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="articleRecentTitre">My great title 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="articleRecentResume"> Excerpt here gregregfdsxgrezgttretgretregergfdqgregregregvcxgretgertrecdsgf'"t"'</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-height">
                 <img src="http://letrainde13h37.fr/wp-content/uploads/authors/jeremie-patonnier.jpg"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="articleRecentTitre">MY great title 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="articleRecentResume">description xaxaxaxaxaxaxaxaxacykaxaxaxafoobarxaxaoifherzoighbnfsoidgneorihgoierhgoihrsfoighvoierhgioreghoireh</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd basically want each column containing a picture to be the size of the biggest picture so that text can align nicely.

I don't think I can use a different row/column layout (putting the two pictures in the same row) because it would put them in the right place (along with the texts) if one was resizing the view / using the site on mobile.

Comment: you need to restrict your image to a particular height with this images in both columns will have the same height and you can give some height to both your divs.

Comment: yeah but if i had a height property to the image it stops being responsive, (since i use the class img-responsive on my imgs) same goes for the divs

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick.  Add this JavaScript to your page.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v30u5zjd/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $("img").each(function () {
        if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    $("img").height(maxHeight);
});
```

Be careful though - scaling the images to be larger than their original size could make for some grainy images.

UPDATE -- check the new fiddle instead.  Added some code to allow for images to remain responsive.  You will need to add img-responsive class to your images.

http://jsfiddle.net/v30u5zjd/3/